# Premium Membership bonus rate?

Tags: happy-wars

I play happy wars once in a while, and when I do, I go on a spree. During that spree, I will often buy and use a premium membership, but am no longer convinced it is worthit.

During normal play, there is no restrictions, or anything else, but as per advertising, you get not-so-hot rewards, and less in-game currency unless you use a premium membership pass.

Now my dillema is that I played 24 hours straight without using a premium membership pass. I got 7 premium items, and lost count at 50 non-premium items.

Using the premium membership pass for 24 hours straight, 24 hours of sleeping later, I got 3 premium items, and lost count at about 70 regular items.

I also seemed much less powerful in-game using the premium membership pass, and because of this, I came out even, or possibly slightly behind on happy stars and EXP for items then when not using a premium pass.

This makes me conclude that it is counter-productive using a premium member pass, however, that opinion is largely biased. I also seem to find it very convienient for ToyLogic that I can't find any hard data on this, on the wiki, or anywhere on the web.

Is there any true hard data, preferably community proven on this issue?

Many thanks!